# jQuery: tagsInput re-init (or unbind everything)

Tags: jquery

I have a tagging plugin (http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/) the only problem is, I often load content into the same DOM - so the `.tagsInput()` gets call again. The problem is, when it happens multiple time, the plugin wont work - so first I need to unbind it somehow, but no internal method...

Comment: please show us your current code

Comment: I really cant show anything... generating content, set the .tagsInput. Then re-generate content, again call .tagsInput

Answer (score 2):

You are not providing much context, but if you want to bind and unbind take a look too `on()` and `off()` on jQuery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
button { margin:5px; }
button#theone { color:red; background:yellow; }
</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="theone">Does nothing...</button>
<button id="bind">Add Click</button>
<button id="unbind">Remove Click</button>
<div style="display:none;">Click!</div>
<script>
function aClick() {
  $("div").show().fadeOut("slow");
}
$("#bind").click(function () {
  $("body").on("click", "#theone", aClick)
    .find("#theone").text("Can Click!");
});
$("#unbind").click(function () {
  $("body").off("click", "#theone", aClick)
    .find("#theone").text("Does nothing...");
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rvaldez/md7y9/)

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround which involves editing *jquery.tagsinput.js* file. Somewhere around lines 200-202 there is a condition

```
if (!id || delimiter[$(this).attr('id')]) {
id = $(this).attr('id', 'tags' + new Date().getTime()).attr('id');
}
```

which needs to be comment out. It solves the "re-generation" problem. Does it create other problems - I dont know, not yet for me.

---

I tracked both variables **id** and **delimiter[$(this).attr('id')]** and found out that even if it is set as parameter - launching function first time the **delimiter[$(this).attr('id')]** is undefined (I wonder why, because it is set in parameters) - condition is false and **id** stays the same - the name of given id. Launching it next time - delimiter is not empty anymore and id equals the same name of given id - condition is true and the new name of id is generated using *getTime*. And this gives the problem- later in the code is kind of impossible to know the correct  *html input id* value.